# IUpdateSearcher performance issues

Tags: c++, windows, performance, wuapi

I am using `IUpdateSession` and `IUpdateSearcher` in an attempt to get a list of available updates for a Windows system.

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,  IID_IUpdateSession, (void**)&pUpdateSession);
if (FAILED(hr) || pUpdateSession == NULL)
{
    return;
}

hr = pUpdateSession->CreateUpdateSearcher(&pUpdateSearcher);
if (FAILED(hr) || pUpdateSearcher == NULL)
{
    return;
}

pUpdateSearcher->put_Online(VARIANT_FALSE);
pUpdateSearcher->put_CanAutomaticallyUpgradeService(VARIANT_FALSE);
pUpdateSearcher->put_IncludePotentiallySupersededUpdates(VARIANT_FALSE);


hr = pUpdateSearcher->Search(BSTR(L"IsInstalled=0 AND IsHidden=0"), &type);
if (FAILED(hr) || type == NULL)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    ... Print results etc. etc.
}
```

This works great when you have a single (or small number) of updates. When testing on a fresh machine with 109 updates available, the `->Search()` call takes over **10 minutes** to process.

Is this normal behaviour, or is there something that can be done to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Other solutions to achieve a list of available updates also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour and I think that you might be searching for updates on a new Windows 7 VM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).